# Extract Contents of DataSet into an Object

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this `DataSet` which calls my `Stored Procedure` and returns a list of integers. How can I extract the list of integers which I could store in a variable be it a collection which grows in size such as a `List<T>` or a primitive data type like an `array` of integers.

Below is my code:

```
 private DataSet getSubGroupsBelongingToUser()
        {
            DataTable variable;
            DataSet DS;
            myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FSK_ServiceMonitor_Users_Management.Properties.Settings.FSK_ServiceMonitorConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
            {
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@UserId", getUserID(cbxSelectUser.Text));
                DS = GetData("Test", param);
                variable = DS.Tables[0];

            }


            return DS;
        }
```

When I hover over the DS magnifier (refer to image):
[image]

I want to retrieve and store that list of integers somewhere. How can I go about doing this? All the examples I came across online make use of linq and that is not applicable here since I am getting the results from my stored procedure which requires one input parameter. Here is the definition of the stored procedure below:

```
create proc [dbo].[Test]
@UserId smallint
as
begin
    select DepartmentSubGroupId from DepartmentSubGroupUser
    where UserId= @UserId
end
GO
```

So essentially when you pass in a UserId, you should get those values. I am using `SQL Server` as my DBMS.

Comment: If you just want a `List<int>` then why use a `DataSet` at all?  You can use a `SqlDataReader` to loop over the results and add each record to your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient approach would be to not use a `DataSet`/`DataTable` at all:

```
private List<int> GetSubGroupsBelongingToUser()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FSK_ServiceMonitor_Users_Management.Properties.Settings.FSK_ServiceMonitorConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Test", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var param = new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(cbxSelectUser.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        con.Open();
        using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rd.Read()) list.Add(rd.GetInt32(0)); 
        }
    } // no need to close the connection with the using

    return list;
}
```

If you insist on the `DataTable`, at least it's more conscise:

```
return DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>(0)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As @David pointed out the simplest option would be to use a `SqlDataReader` and loop through all the records.

However, if your heart is set on `DataTable`s then all you need to do is to iterate all rows from the result table, grab the value from column `DepartmentSubGroupId` and add it to a list. You can do that with Linq also like this:

```
return DS.Tables[0].Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>() // Rows is an ICollection and you need to cast each item
    .Select(r => (int)r["DepartmentSubGroupId"]) // For each row get the value from column DepartmentSubGroupId 
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I saw @Tim's solution, I had already prepared this (which works just as well as most of the above solutions):

```
        public List<int> getSubGroupsBelongingToUser()
        {
            List<int> DepartmentSubGroupIds = new List<int>();

            myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FSK_ServiceMonitor_Users_Management.Properties.Settings.FSK_ServiceMonitorConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
            {
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@UserId", getUserID(cbxSelectUser.Text));
                mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("Test", mySQLConnection);
                mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                mySQLConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                mySQLConnection.Open();

                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    DepartmentSubGroupIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["DepartmentSubGroupId"]));
                }
            }
            return DepartmentSubGroupIds;
        }
```

Thanks everybody, much appreciated.